# Doubt in proof of Prop 2.2.2 in Kesavan's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Given a normed linear space $V$ (with norm $\lVert \rVert_{V}$) and a closed subspace $W$, Kesavan defines a norm $\lVert \rVert_{V/W}$ on the quotient space $V/W$ as $\lVert x+W \rVert_{V/W} = \inf_{w \in W} \lVert x +w \rVert_{V}$. Then he proceeds to show that this norm is well defined.

**Prop. 2.2.2** (pg. 36) claims that if $(V, \lVert \rVert_{V})$ is Banach, then $(V/W, \lVert \rVert_{V/W})$ is also Banach. The proof goes as follows:

Take a Cauchy sequence $\{x_i + W\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in $V/W$. Then extract a subsequence $\{x_{n_k} + W\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lVert x_{n_k} + W - (x_{n_{k+1}} + W) \rVert_{V/W} < \frac{1}{2^k}$. (I'm able to understand till this step)

Then the author chooses a sequence $\{y_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $y_k \in x_{n_k} +W$ and $\lVert y_k - y_{k+1} \rVert_{V} < \frac{1}{2^k}$. Then he observes that $\{y_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy and so converges to some $y$ since $V$ is Banach. Then a straightforward argument shows that $\{x_{n_k} + W\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $y+W$ and does the entire sequence $\{x_i + W\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

I'm not able to see how the author chooses the sequence $\{y_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. I am only able to find a sequence $\{w_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lVert x_{n_k} - x_{n_{k+1}} + w_k \rVert_{V} < \frac{1}{2^k}$. I'm not sure how to construct $\{y_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ from $\{w_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

I would appreciate some help to see how author chooses $\{y_{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to select the sequence:

- From $\inf_{w\in W}\|x_{n_1}-x_{n_2}+w\|_V < \frac{1}{2}$ we get that there exists a $w_2 \in W$ such that $\|x_{n_1}-(x_{n_2}-w_2)\|_V < \frac{1}{2}$. Set $y_1 = x_{n_1}$ and $y_2 = x_{n_2}-w_2$.
- Since $w_2 \in W$ we have
  $$\inf_{w\in W}\|(x_{n_2}-w_2) - x_{n_3} + w\|_V=\inf_{w\in W}\|x_{n_2}-x_{n_3}+w\|_V<\frac{1}{2^2}$$
  and hence there exists some $w_3 \in W$ such that $\|(x_{n_2}-w_2) - (x_{n_3} - w_3)\|_V < \frac{1}{2^2}$. Set $y_3 = x_{n_3}-w_3$.

Continuing this way we get the required sequence $\{y_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.